# How can I show the $n$ distinct $n$th roots of 1 are equally spaced around a circle centered at the origin with radius 1?

Tags: abstract-algebra, roots-of-unity

My work:

To show that the radius = 1 centered at the origin, I can employ the distance formula:
$\sqrt{(r^{1/n}cos((\theta + 2k\pi)/n)-0)^2+(r^{1/n}isin((\theta + 2k\pi)/n)-0)^2}=\sqrt{r^{2/n}[cos^2((\theta + 2k\pi)/n)-sin^2((\theta + 2k\pi)/n)]}.$

However, I do not know where to go from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the polar form, so one root is at $re^{i\theta}$.  Raise that to the $n^{th}$ power, getting $r^ne^{in\theta}$.  You need $r^n=1, n\theta=2k\pi$

Comment: How do we start with the initial root at $re^{i\theta}$? And why are we raising to the $n$th power?

Comment: You are trying to solve $z^n=1$. The polar form for $z$ is convenient. Then we note that $1=1e^{i2k\pi}$

Comment: Is the equality $1=e^{i2k\pi}$ a well-established identity? I have seen this multiple times now. Also, you claim that we need $r^n=1$ and $n\theta = 2k\pi$. Is this to satisfy that the circle is centered at the origin and the radius is 1? I just want to understand how you are proving this. Thank you!

Comment: How would you show that this is a circle centered at the origin?

Comment: It comes from $e^{i \theta}=\cos \theta + i \sin \theta$.  When $\theta$ is a multiple of $2 \pi$ the cosine is $+1$ and the sine is $0$.  The Pythagorean identity shows all these points are $1$ from the origin, so are on a circle.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you!